# Change color of ctrl + f search results in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, search, colors, find, chromium

i'm looking for any way to change the yellowish stock color of ctrl + f search results in chromium based browser (opera in my case). I tried to research this topic, but i didn't find any way to do that in chromium. I would appreciate your answers, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good place to search for that information:

Media Access Australia

https://mediaaccess.org.au/web/web-browsers/how-to-turn-on-accessibility-features-in-google-chrome